# How do you hide the ends of a plane?

Tags: modeling, cycles-render-engine, modifiers, 3d-view, edit-mode

I am trying to make an environment (using a plane for the ground) and I need to hide the ends of the plane. I have tried adjusting the size but i need to make it ridiculously wide to hide the ends.

Currently:
[image]

What I'd like to achieve (without changing the scale of the plane):
[image]

The above image is if i scale the plane a lot by the y axis. What could I do?

Answer (score 2):

When making landscapes  things to consider 1ST - Very Important - Your Camera angle and your camera view. How much of the Landscape is going to be visible thru your camera only make and entertain the Landscape till there. 2nd - Each and every 3d landscape you see are overlaid / Overlapped onto one another so that there boundaries just disappear somewhere while overlapping and then further covered with additional rock/plant/grass/debris etc details.[image]

Consider this your landscape and think about what I mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

Two things can be done, 1st Simply move those vertices under another plane or any other landscape nearby. 2nd Snap those vertices to another Meshes nearby that mesh, And also if you do this you might have to increase the subdivision so that you can snap the whole boundary of the plane and not just the 2 vertices, onto another mesh especially if the 2nd mesh is distorted.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean when you said to move the vertices under another plane?